# importing css rules

Tags: css, optimization, import

This is real simple. Is there a way to import CSS rules, not an entire sheet, into another stylesheet.

For example, say I want just the rules for `p, blockquote, #main, and .red` to be in a stylesheet, but no other rules, like simple OOP. Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with CSS, and this is one of the reasons for the recent development of (and growth in the use of) preprocessors like LESS and SASS.

Comment: I figured as much. It seems beyond the design of normal CSS. It seems to me that it is a very good thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the common pieces into a single file and call them from two other files.  You can use CSS @Import for this: http://www.cssnewbie.com/css-import-rule/

The problem with this approach is that it means that the web browsers have to download more files and it slows the load process of sites down considerably.   Here is an article about it: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/